# Project Reactor: Do I need a Processor?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor, reactive-streams

I'm trying to design a pipeline framework on top of Reactor.

At each stage (not considering the first and the last), we have tasks that transform an object (i.e. string to its length or a url to its HTML content etc). Here's an example:

[image]

You can see that the middle layer has 3 tasks and each task transforms an X object to a Y object (by the way, it's always a fully connected layers)

**My Question/Dilemma:** 
My first thought was that all I need is to `Flux.merge()` and then, to connect it to each Subscriber. For example:

```
Flux<X> source = Flux.merge(x1Flux, x2Flux)  
source.subscribe(y1Subscriber)
source.subscribe(y2Subscriber)
```

Another option is to put a Processor (TopicProcessor?) that will act as a middleware (like in the pub-sub pattern)

I'm lacking the understanding of which solution fits best to my problem. Logically it's the same, but what are the practical implications of each architecture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My general approach here would be to use `ConnectableFlux` so as to delay the publishing until you have your entire pipeline setup, and then call `connect()` on each flux once you've set up the pipeline.

You *could* use a processor, but I'd advise avoiding that wherever possible.

The general gist (not checked for syntax) would be something akin to:

```
ConnectableFlux<String> x1 = Flux.just("x1").publish();
ConnectableFlux<String> x2 = Flux.just("x2").publish();

ConnectableFlux<String> y1 = Flux.<String>from(Flux.merge(x1, x2)).publish();
ConnectableFlux<String> y2 = Flux.<String>from(Flux.merge(x1, x2)).publish();
ConnectableFlux<String> y3 = Flux.<String>from(Flux.merge(x1, x2)).publish();

ConnectableFlux<String> z3 = Flux.<String>from(Flux.merge(y1, y2, y3)).publish();

x1.connect();
x2.connect();
y1.connect();
//...etc.
```

Also note that you may wish to use `concat()` or `mergeSequential()` rather than `merge()`, depending on your use case (`merge()` will subscribe to publishers eagerly, `concat()` will not, and `mergeSequential()` will merge in the order received, potentially interleaving the values.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! Actually, this needs to be an indefinite process so I think `merge` or `mergeSequential` is needed, right?

Comment: @yaseco Correct. `concat()` will wait for the first stream to complete before moving onto the next, so in the case of infinite streams it'll never complete.

Comment: that `Flux.from(...::subscribe)` part seems fishy (usually a code smell to have a subscribe in the middle of a reactive chain like this). Why did you include it instead of  simply `Flux.merge(x1, x2).publish())`?